# ClearMyTracksByProcess - all options?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, rundll32.exe

I've seen the list of values floating around the internet for ClearMyTracksByProcess

```
Delete Temporary Internet Files:
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

Delete Cookies:
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

Delete History:
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

Delete Form Data:
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

Delete Passwords:
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32

Delete All:
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

Delete All + files and settings stored by Add-ons:
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351
```

But it's not a complete list of all the options, and I can't seem to find a complete list (whether there isn't one published, or this one has been republished too many times and is hogging all the search results, I'm not sure).

What I'm looking to do is delete Cookies + Temp + Add-ons, but preserve History, Form data, and Passwords. Has anybody found a complete list of all the available options?  Or just the option for Add-ons so I can do the math myself? (e.g. Add-ons value + 8 + 2 = the answer I'm looking for)

Thanks for looking at my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Selenium IEDriver sources](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/92c0da7299ea040fdc6d7d287296c397bc5c9fca#diff-cf132f5561101876cdfe807f013ddddcR61) :

```fs
// This magic value is the combination of the following bitflags:
// #define CLEAR_HISTORY         0x0001 // Clears history
// #define CLEAR_COOKIES         0x0002 // Clears cookies
// #define CLEAR_CACHE           0x0004 // Clears Temporary Internet Files folder
// #define CLEAR_CACHE_ALL       0x0008 // Clears offline favorites and download history
// #define CLEAR_FORM_DATA       0x0010 // Clears saved form data for form auto-fill-in
// #define CLEAR_PASSWORDS       0x0020 // Clears passwords saved for websites
// #define CLEAR_PHISHING_FILTER 0x0040 // Clears phishing filter data
// #define CLEAR_RECOVERY_DATA   0x0080 // Clears webpage recovery data
// #define CLEAR_PRIVACY_ADVISOR 0x0800 // Clears tracking data
// #define CLEAR_SHOW_NO_GUI     0x0100 // Do not show a GUI when running the cache clearing
//
// Bitflags available but not used in this magic value are as follows:
// #define CLEAR_USE_NO_THREAD      0x0200 // Do not use multithreading for deletion
// #define CLEAR_PRIVATE_CACHE      0x0400 // Valid only when browser is in private browsing mode
// #define CLEAR_DELETE_ALL         0x1000 // Deletes data stored by add-ons
// #define CLEAR_PRESERVE_FAVORITES 0x2000 // Preserves cached data for "favorite" websites
#define CLEAR_CACHE_OPTIONS 0x09FF
```

From [winaero.com/blog](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-delete-the-browsing-history-in-internet-explorer-11/) :

```fs
// Delete only download history    
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16384
```

Comment: FYI 16384 is the same as 0x4000

Answer (score 4):

I know this was answered a while ago but I thought my post might make it easier for someone who finds the question as I did.

The following can be run from CMD or in a script (I tested Batch and VBS). The parameter "ClearMyTracksByProcess" was case sensitive in all of my tests.  That might differ by OS and I didn't test anything other than Windows 8.1.

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess <number>
```

The  parameter is required and is derived from some combination of the following values, represented as a decimal number.

```
1    = Browsing History
2    = Cookies
4    = Temporary Internet Files
8    = Offline favorites and download history
16   = Form Data
32   = Passwords
64   = Phishing Filter Data
128  = Web page Recovery Data
256  = Do not Show GUI when running the cache clear
512  = Do not use Multi-threading for deletion
1024 = Valid only when browser is in private browsing mode
2048 = Tracking Data
4096 = Data stored by add-ons
8192 = Preserves Cached data for Favorite websites
```

Add values together to get aggregate functionality.  For example '4' is deleting all temporary internet files and '260' is doing the same without the dialog being displayed while it purges.

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 260
```

Answer (score 1):

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess # wouldn't touch the real cache folder "Low" (that's where protected mode IE stores the data). The command won't be effective if not run with a low integrity level. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447236/how-can-i-delete-internet-explorer-cookies-using-bat-script