# Windows 7 How to clear Internet Explorer SSL State/Cache from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, internet-explorer, cmd.exe

On my work computer we have to use Internet Explorer and I'm constantly going back and forth between site on the intranet as well as external sites.  I find that at least 15 times per day I'm clearing my [SSL State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JBV1.png) in order to reach these sites.  I'd like to do this with a simple batch file.

I found a question that explained [how to use the clearmytracksbyprocess](https://superuser.com/questions/450014/clearmytracksbyprocess-all-options); however, I'm unsure of which integer option/combination of options represents clearing the [SSL State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JBV1.png).  Any and all guidance on running that option would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's the "SSL State", not "slate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I clear the Internet Explorer SSL State/Cache from command line

Use the following command:

> "C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll",DispatchAPICall 3

Source [Clear SSL State using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13397277/3536342), answer by [Ingo Karkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat)