# Bat file to exit an application delete files and folders from %temp% and Cisco jabber folders , flush dns cache

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, jabber

I need help with code for .bat file should do following operations:

1. Exit Cisco Jabber application.

Delete files and folders from following locations:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

2. Reset IE
3. Flush DNS cache.

   Below is the sample code I found from this forum.

```
@ECHO OFF
    
SET THEDIR0=C:\Users\lashley\AppData\Local\Temp\
    
Echo Deleting all files from %THEDIR0% DEL "%THEDIR0%\*" /F /Q /A
    
Echo Deleting all folders from %THEDIR0% FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%THEDIR0%\*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%THEDIR0%\%%I" @ECHO Folder deleted.
    
  
SET THEDIR1=C:\Users\saiku\Desktop\New folder\New folder\
    
Echo Deleting all files from %THEDIR1% DEL "%THEDIR1%\*" /F /Q /A
    
Echo Deleting all folders from %THEDIR1% FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%THEDIR1%\*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%THEDIR1%\%%I" @ECHO Folder deleted.
    
    
SET THEDIR2=C:\Users\saiku\Desktop\New folder\New folders\
    
    
Echo Deleting all files from %THEDIR2% DEL "%THEDIR2%\*" /F /Q /A
    
Echo Deleting all folders from %THEDIR2% FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%THEDIR2%\*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%THEDIR2%\%%I" @ECHO Folder deleted.
    
EXIT
```

- Note: I had to manually run this .bat file as admin for this to work. Can this code be modified such way that it works with a single click?
- Note2: I want this code to work on any computer irrespective of computer name or user account of the computer:

  Example:
  `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Cisco\Unified Communications`
  I want Unified Communication folder to be deleted in this case

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments in the code tagged with "REM":

```
@ECHO OFF
REM *Exit Cisco Jabber application.*
REM *Replace "notepad.exe" with the filename of the Jabber application*
SET processname=notepad.exe
tasklist | find /i %processname% && taskkill /im notepad.exe /F || echo process %processname% not running.

REM *Delete files*
REM *I think you have it to run as administrator because you want to access the TEMP folder.*
REM *As a work around you could change the access rights of this folder for all local users. Consider the security issues with this*
SET THEDIR0=%temp%    
Echo Deleting all files from %THEDIR0% DEL "%THEDIR0%\*" /F /Q /A
Echo Deleting all folders from %THEDIR0% FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%THEDIR0%\*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%THEDIR0%\%%I" @ECHO Folder deleted.
SET THEDIR1=%userprofile%\Desktop\New folder\New folder\
Echo Deleting all files from %THEDIR1% DEL "%THEDIR1%\*" /F /Q /A
Echo Deleting all folders from %THEDIR1% FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%THEDIR1%\*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%THEDIR1%\%%I" @ECHO Folder deleted.
SET THEDIR2=%userprofile%\Desktop\New folder\New folders\
Echo Deleting all files from %THEDIR2% DEL "%THEDIR2%\*" /F /Q /A
Echo Deleting all folders from %THEDIR2% FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%THEDIR2%\*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%THEDIR2%\%%I" @ECHO Folder deleted.


REM Reset IE
REM What do you mean with this exactly?
REM Do you want to reload a webpage or would restart the browser be enought?

REM Flush DNS
ipconfig /flushdns

EXIT
```

Comment: Thank you.
Reset IE - Reset Internet explorer settings from Internet options > Advance > Reset.

Comment: It is answered on above post. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```file-bat
@Echo off & CD/d "%~dp0"

Set "_dir=Roaming,Local"
Echo\Killing iE and Jabber!...
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

%:^(
For %%i in ("CiscoJabber.exe", "CiscoJabberPrt.exe",iexplore.exe
)do Rem./ & 2>nul >nul "%__APPDIR__%Taskkill.exe" /f /t /im %%~I

;Echo\Checking if still running... && for %%i in (CiscoJabber,iExplore
)do 2>nul "%__APPDIR__%Tasklist.exe" /nh |Find/i "%%i.exe" >nul && Goto %:^(

>nul 2>&1 "%__APPDIR__%RunDll32.exe" InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351

%:^)
(%__APPDIR__%Tasklist.exe |Find/i "CiscoJabber.exe" >nul || For %%i in (!_dir!)do (
   If /i exist "%UserProfile%\AppData\%%~i\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\*" (
       CD /d "%UserProfile%\AppData\%%~i\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\" && (
       cmd/v/c "Echo\Deleting: !cd! & RMdir/q/s "!cd!." & Echo\\Deleted: !cd!\" )))
       ) 2>nul & "%__APPDIR__%Tasklist.exe" |Find/i "CiscoJabber" >nul && Goto %:^(

;Rem./ && Echo\Deleting: %tmp% & 2>nul RMDir/q /s "%tmp%\." & Echo\\Deleted: %tmp%\
;Rem./ && "%__APPDIR__%IPConfig.exe" /flushdns|Find/i "DNS" & Endlocal && Goto=:EOF
```

---

- Outputs:

```file-bat
Killing iE and Jabber!...
Checking if still running...
Deleting: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber
\Deleted: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\
Deleting: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber
\Deleted: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\
Deleting: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp
\Deleted: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\
Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

---

**Obs.: 1** iE Commands Souces: **[@R L H](https://superuser.com/a/1006718/969781)** **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1006718/969781)**

**Obs.: 2** A suggestion with the `for` loop, in case you need several iE commands to reset/clean/remove:

```file-bat
For %%i in ( 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 4351, 8192
)do 2>nul >nul "%__APPDIR__%RunDll32.exe" InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess %%i

   1 == Browsing History
   2 == Cookies
   4 == Temporary Internet Files
   8 == Offline favorites and download history
  16 == Form Data
  32 == Passwords
  64 == Phishing Filter Data
 128 == Web page Recovery Data
 256 == Do not Show GUI when running the cache clear
 512 == Do not use Multi-threading for deletion
1024 == Valid only when browser is in private browsing mode
2048 == Tracking Data
4096 == Data stored by add-ons
4351 == Delete all w/Data stored by add-ons
8192 == Preserves Cached data for Favorite websites
```

---

- An alternative (conventional / slightly simpler)
  with the same outputs, would be:

```file-bat
@Echo off 

CD /d "%~dp0"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

:to_kill_process
For %%i in (CiscoJabber.exe,CiscoJabberPrt.exe,iexplore.exe)do (
     "%__APPDIR__%Taskkill.exe" /f /t /im %%~i
    ) 2>nul >nul

Echo\Stop/Kill iE and/or CiscoJabber... & echo\

For %%i in (CiscoJabber.exe,CiscoJabberPrt.exe,iexplore.exe)do (
     "%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe" /nh |Find/i "%%i.exe" 
    ) 2>nul >nul&& Goto :to_kill_process
    
<con: Set /p "=Resetting iExplorer." <nul && (
     "%__APPDIR__%RunDll32.exe" InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351
     ) && echo\ is Done..
echo\..done!

:to_del_folders
   ( 
     %__APPDIR__%Tasklist.exe |Find/i "CiscoJabber.exe" >nul 
    ) || (
     For %%i in (!_dir!) do If /i exist "%UserProfile%\AppData\%%~i\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\*" (
        (
          CD /d "%UserProfile%\AppData\%%~i\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\"
        ) && (
         Echo\ & cmd.exe /v:on /c "Echo\Deleting: !cd! & RMdir /q /s "!cd!." & Echo\\Deleted: !cd!\" 
        )
        )
        ) 2>nul
            
"%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe" | Find/i "CiscoJabber" >nul && Goto :to_kill_process
       
Echo\ & Echo\Deleting: %tmp%

2>nul RMDir/q /s "%tmp%\."

Echo\\Deleted: %tmp%\ & Echo/

<con: Set /p "=Cleaning up DNsServerCache: " <nul 
"%__APPDIR__%ipconfig.exe" /flushdns |find/i "DNS"

Endlocal & Goto :EOF
```

---

- Outputs:

```file-bat
Stop/Kill iE and/or CiscoJabber...

Resetting iExplorer...done

Deleting: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber
\Deleted: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Roaming\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\

Deleting: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber
\Deleted: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Cisco\Unified Communications\Jabber\

Deleting: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp
\Deleted: C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\

Cleaning up DNsServerCache: Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

---